# ASP.NET MVC Controller actions with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got a controller in MVC5 for an apply form. There is a GET to return the view and a POST to take the form data from the application and process it:-

```
public ActionResult Apply(string jobReference)
{
   Apply form = new Apply();
   Session[Settings.JOBREFERENCE] = jobReference;
   return View(form);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Apply(Apply form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
}
```

When I press the  to submit the form, it calls the GET controller instead of the the POST controller, despite it having [HttpPost] on the latter.

If I actively renamed the HTTPPost controller and navigate to it, I see a Server Error, with a message saying it cannot be found. Submitting the form causes the page to crash.

**Form Code**

```
    @model Salt.Models.Apply
<div class='applyForRoleExt popupBox'>
    <a href="#" class="closePopup"><img src="/img/closePopup.png" alt="close" /></a>
    <div class="innerContainer">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Apply", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "ApplyForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <h6>Apply for this role</h6>
            @*<div class="haveAccount">
                    <span>Have an account? Apply quickly by logging in now</span>
                    <a href="#" class="loginApply">Login to my account</a>
                </div>*@
            <div class="leftCol">
                <label>Name<span>*</span></label>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                </div>
                <label>Email Address<span>*</span></label>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
                </div>
                <label>Telephone Number<span>*</span></label>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TelephoneNumber)
                </div>
                <label>Portfolio Link<span>*</span></label>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PortfolioLink)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightCol">
                <label>CV Upload</label>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CV, new { @type = "file" })
                </div>
                <label>Covering Note</label>
                <div class="inputArea">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CoveringNote)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <p class="terms">By submitting this form you consent to Salt Recruitment processing your personal data in accordance with our privacy policy and agree to future contact material.</p>
                <!--<button class="submit">Apply Now</button>-->
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Apply Now" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#ApplyForm");
    });
</script>
```

Thanks,
Mike.

Comment: Remove [ActionName("Apply")] in all code.

Comment: ActionName("Apply") has been removed from my code now. On the Form I have


using (Html.BeginForm("JobApply", "Form", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "ApplyForm" }))

Comment: Also, now that these changes have been made, and I've changed the post to "JobApply". I've changed the controller to JobApply accepting the Apply class as a model. I receive 404 Not Found. Routing issue maybe?

Comment: @MikeUpjohn You need to post the form code too. You will need to make sure you are actually submitting a post, you might have an actionlink instead of an input with type post.

Comment: Are you sure that you are including @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your form post?

Comment: To backup @hutchonoid comment, it would be handy to see your `Html.BeginForm()` related code.

Comment: Added above. Sorry it took a while.

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed. It took a second pair of eyes but a rule in the web.config was removing the trailing slash from the form post URL and it was defaulting to loading the GET. No idea why that would cause the problem but it did.